# call function if attribute value has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is not a duplicate, because the value of the input is changed by a function, not by user input.

Is it possible to call a function if the value of the attribute of an element has changed?

E.g. I use an input text with the id **color** and a button which opens a color picker. If I select a color then the color value is written into the input text with id **color**.

[image: Color Picker]

I try to detect if the value of the input text with id **color** has changed and call a function which sets the `background-color` of my input text to the selected color.

**My attempt:**

```
$("input#color").on
(
    "change",
    function()
    {
        console.log("SOMETHING HAS CHANGED");

        var color = $("input#color").val();
        $("input#color").css("background-color", color);
    }
);
```

But `SOMETHING HAS CHANGED` is never shown.

I know I could solve this by using timers, but I think there must be a better solution.

Comment: Its running properly, did you've add jquery files?

Comment: Jquery file is included and the color picker itself is working. Jquery also works, if i change the event from `change` to `click` then something happens after the click.

Comment: Change is only triggered when it loses focus and was changed. The best way to continually check and respond to change is to... Continually check if something has changed, with an interval for example.

Comment: I know that i could use an interval, but is this the only solution?! I was not planning to code it like this because i thought it would be a dirty workaround.

Comment: Do one thing listen to the color picker click event or check where is setting value in your input. After value set call trigger change event of the input.

Comment: Yes thats also possible and it seems like this is my only option.